# How to use Sinch SDK with Swift project without Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I am trying to use the Sinch SDK with swift project without using Cocoapods, since I have to support iOS 7.0.

I have downloaded the Sinch SDK and added the Sinch.framework to my projects Linked Frameworks and Libraries section.

Now I do not have any idea about how to get started. I am using the bridging header file to link Objective C files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to use Cocoapods as well as support iOS 7.

If you use Cocoapods with `use_frameworks` keywords in it. It will force you to make the minimum iOS version to iOS 8.0. Since it make dynamic frameworks.

So the solution is to comment the `use_frameworks`.

The Podfile I am using right now is below.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TheSinchSampleProject' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TheSinchSampleProject
 pod 'SinchRTC', '~> 3.9'
end
```